# Memcached error - The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Tags: dependencies

I know it's my first post, I will say though I have used this site for a lot of resources and tips. So thank you for that!

I am hosting with DO and have a droplet with an issue, we're running a live site and I need a caching system in place. 
Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
I've tried installing memcached but keep getting this error;

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-memcached : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9 is to be installed
```

I've searched and tried many different suggestions - but truth be told, I'm not getting anywhere..
Was just wondering if anyone would be so kind to put forward any suggestions.

I did manage to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` which worked, but afterwards and again, I couldn't install Memcached.

I tried a VNC connection and tried Synaptic, but I couldn't get Synaptic to run as VNC user (I think it needs root privileges). VNC ran fine, I have since removed.

Any help would be greatly received, and thank you very much in advance.

After performing another `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install memcached`

And I get the following;

```
 sudo apt-get install memcached
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
memcached is already the newest version.
```

So it IS installed, but that's not the full installation as I am still having this issue..
Any help would be most welcomed.
Thank you!